# Retrieving data from JSON URL

Tags: javascript, json

These are my JavaScript, CSS and HTML code. I cannot retrieve the lat and lng the Google API. It always show a blank page without any data from the url.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=YOUR_API_KEY',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
    drawTable(data);
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }

}

function drawRow(rowData) {
   var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); 
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lat + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lng + "</td>"));
 
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Json to HTML</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<table id="personDataTable">

    <tr>
        <th>Lat</th>
        <th>Lng</th>
        
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all you should hide your Api Key. , i will take a look when i get free times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as a rule of thumb, never publish your API key. The API key is the value attached to the key parameter in your AJAX request.

Second, you have neither provided a failure callback nor verified the data returned from the aforementioned request (in your success callback).

I would highly suggest you add these changes to your code and check what you see (with some logs).

One thing that comes to mind is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue, but I can't be sure since I don't have enough information about where you are running this code from.

Comment: I tried testing with a different url and data id and it works but it doesn't work with my own url.

Comment: I added 
success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    $("#container").html(data);
    alert("Local success callback.");
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
    alert("Local error callback.");
  },
  complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
    alert("Local completion callback.");
  }
to my code but there is no success or error.
Sorry, i'm new to coding.

Comment: @Berwyn, I don't understand what it means that you tested it with a different url(which url? What's the original url?). Nevertheless, if what you are saying is true, then it is probably a Cross-Origin-Domain issue. Meaning, that you are trying to access a different domain then the one you are on. Read more [here](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/)

Comment: the actual link is https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and the rowData is id instead of lat and lng. I changed the url and rowData and it does not load anymore. There is no error or success too.

Comment: [Here](https://odan.github.io/2017/07/16/finding-coordinates-by-address-with-the-google-maps-api.html) is an example, albeit in php, but it should help you.

Comment: @Berwyn - If my answer helped you, then please mark it as the answer.